# recursive query in crystal reports

Tags: recursion, crystal-reports

I have records composed of {employee name, position type, manager name}. I need to reduce the variable-depth tree structure of executives, managers and employees to a three-tier structure of executives, managers, and employees such that each employee is associated with the top-level manager in their department and that manager's executive. I can use the position type to get this information while joining on manager name and employee name, but is it even possible to do this recursive calculation/query in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a pair of self-joins. Basically, just add 3 aliased copies of the employee table to the report and join them like this:

{Employee_ALIAS1.Manager_Name} → {EmployeeALIAS2.Name}

{Employee_ALIAS2.Manager_Name} → {EmployeeALIAS3.Name}

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your response. Just to make sure, this looks like it would work for a static three tier tree, which is my goal, but not my start point. Or an I misunderstanding your solution?